# Organizing Multiple Details Sections in Crystal Reports 2013

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm creating a report in Crystal Reports 2013 that will show the same metrics for a variety of different views. I'd like to layer them on top of each other vertically in different detail sections.

I'll try to explain best I can. I'm inserting the first query into the first report detail ('Details a'); this query has two rows.

I'm then inserting a similar query into another details section ('Details B'). I'd like each row in Details A to presented at the top of the report, and then each row of 'Details B' presented underneath that( So:

Details A Row 1

Details A Row 2

Details B Row 1

Details B Row 2

My problem is, when I go to Preview, the rows are organized like this:

Details A Row 1

Details B Row 1

Details A Row 2

Details B Row 2

Is there anyway to format Details sections so I can keep all rows within each details section next to each other? Please let me know if more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 subreports (Insert, Subreport).
This would allow subreport #1 to show all details rows from one data source. 
And subreport #2 would show all details rows from the other data source.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is a cartesian product. In other words, the set of your first query brings 2 rows, while the set of you second brings another 2 rows. So, 2x2=4 rows.

Another thing to notice, is that details A and B are not independent. That is not very intuitive, i know. Let me try to tell you how Crystal deal with that (it is not how it really works, just an helpful view to understand it):

1. Crystal executes your two queries. 
   The result of the first query has 2 items, namely 1 and 2. 
   The result of the second query has other 2 items, namely 3 and 4.
2. Crystal check the link between the two result sets. Since - i suppose - you did not tell to Crystal what is that link, Crystal suppose there are no links, so it makes the cartesian product resulting in 4 rows, namely 1/3, 1/4, 2/3, 2/4.
3. Then Crystal makes a kind of "foreach" statement. So, foreach of the 4 rows, it prints one instance of the details section.
4. Since your details section has 2 subsections, namely details A and details B, it will end up with 4 details printing, as you saw:

> ```
> 1 //1st detail section, subsection A, field from 1st result set
> 3 //1st detail section, subsection B, field from 2nd result set
> 1 //2nd detail section, subsection A, field from 1st result set
> 4 //2nd detail section, subsection B, field from 2nd result set (second item)
> 2 //3st detail section, subsection A, field from 1st result set (second item)
> 3 //3st detail section, subsection B, field from 2nd result set
> 2 //4nd detail section, subsection A, field from 1st result set (second item)
> 4 //4nd detail section, subsection B, field from 2nd result set (second item)
> ```

So, as @MilletSoftware already pointed out (while i was writing this, hahah), the simplest solution is to use two subreports.

Comment: thank you for this explanation. You're correct in that I cleared all links when I inserted each query into the report. This helps me understand what was going on on a more intuitive level.